# Cloud Foundry on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, cloud-foundry, jackrabbit-oak

My application has Jackrabbit Oak implementation, so it uses direct binary upload features through S3DataStore for storing files on AWS-S3. For AWS-S3 integration, we had created service broker instance on Cloud Foundry which was on our on-premises server.

Now I moved Cloud Foundry on Google Cloud Platform, but when I am trying to search AWS-S3 service broker using `cf marketplace` command. I could not see the aws-s3 service broker.

How to get aws-s3 service broker and if it is not possible then, is there any way to integrate aws-s3 storage with application deployed on CloudFoundry on GCP in case of above scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you had deployed on your platform as we don't have any context of what was installed there. Just a guess, but it sounds like you had the Tanzu AWS Service Broker installed. It has service offerings for `aws-s3`.

https://docs.pivotal.io/aws-services/creating.html#view

You can still install the Tanzu AWS Service Broker when running Tanzu Application Service on top of GCP, you just need to have a AWS account where the broker will create your service instances. The broker creates AWS resources on behalf of the users and it does it under a given AWS account, so as long as you still have an AWS account you can make it work.

That said, there's also a GCP broker that functions in the same, so if you are trying to move off AWS to GCP entirely you could look at using the GCP broker instead. GCP has a similar cloud storage offering.

https://docs.pivotal.io/partners/gcp-sb/index.html

Once you install either broker, you'll see the service plan offerings in your marketplace. If you're still not seeing them, check `cf service-access` as an admin user. You may need to enable access to those services with `cf enable-service-access`.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the team that moved you between CF/AWS and CF/GCP and tell them you need your S3 broker back :)